# NE555P Frequency Drop to 0 after a couple of minutes?

Tags: arduino, frequency, frequency-measurement, atmega328p, 555

I'm trying to build a frequency measurement circuit using NE555P and Atmega328P. The circuit is the following : [image]

I use this library https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_FreqCount.html

Always, The system works fine at the beginning (3 to 4 minutes) and then the frequency values start to drop until reaching 0.

Does anyone knows what causes this strange behaviour ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please try to find a blurrier picture of the schematic?

Comment: @DerStrom8 http://morejpeg.com/Image/View/471237a9-e72f-e711-80e2-816ff0a4276e . *You're welcome*.

Comment: Is this the *literal* opportunity to VTC for being *unclear*?

Comment: A fuzzy question, indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very difficult to see, but as far as I can tell it looks like you have the wrong pinout for the 555 timer. The pins on the right-hand side should be numbered 5-8 from the bottom up, not from the top down:

[image]

If you have it connected the way the picture shows, I expect that's why it's giving you problems.

Comment: +1 for eagle eyes... I did not spot that.